# How do I loop through the value of a field in a table column?

Tags: oracle

I have a table naprav, where there are fields naprav_id and naprav_name, trying to write something like this:

```
For naprav_id in (select naprav_id from naprav)
Loop
select naprav_name from narrow where to.napravit=napravit
End loop;
```

I understand that this code is meaningless, but it is necessary to be able to go through the value of the fields in the loop. How can this be adequately implemented?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=577d3b33c2ff7c1ebe078a18baa4cfab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that would be something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_naprav_name naprav.naprav_name%type;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select naprav_id from naprav) loop
  5      select naprav_name
  6        into l_naprav_name
  7        from naprav
  8        where naprav_id = cur_r.naprav_id;
  9
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_naprav_name);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```